# Show $G:=\{ f\in L(V,V) \mid f^{-1}=f^{ad}\}$ is a subgroup

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory

> Let $dim(V)<\infty$. Let $G:=\{ f\in L(V,V) \mid f^{-1}=f^{ad}\}$ and $S(V)=\{ f\in L(V,V) \mid f\, \text{is bijective}\}$. I want to show that $G$ is a subgroup of $S(V)$.

Thus we have to show:

$\bullet \text{G is not empty}\\
\bullet \text{for all f and g in S(V): f,g in G }\to\text{ f+g in G  }\\
\bullet \text{for all f in S(V) also }f^{-1} \in G
$

$\bullet$ G is not empty since $F=Id_V$ is bijective and $Id_V^{-1}=Id_V=Id_v^{ad}. $ Thus $F \in G$

*EDIT*

To the second bullet: $(f\circ g)^{ad}=g^{ad}\circ f^{ad}=g^{-1}\circ f^{-1}=(f\circ g)^{-1}$

To the third bullet: $Id_V=(f\circ f^{-1})=(f\circ f^{-1})^{ad}=f^{{ad}^{-1}}\circ f^{ad}=f^{{-1}^{-1}}\circ f^{-1}=f\circ f^{-1}=(f^{-1}\circ f)$ Thus $f$ has an inverse element and therefore is a subgroup of G.

P.S. I have mistaken subvectore space with subgroup. But this should hold now.

Comment: What does $f^{ad}$ mean here?

Comment: it denotes the adjungated function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The group operation in $S(V)$ is *composition*, and it is not closed under addition (i.e. $id, -id$ are invertible but their sum is not), or multiplication by $0$.

And, yes, a fixed basis (or an inner product)  in $V$ is assumed to be able to interpret $f^{ad} $.

Comment: Yes you are right. I have mistaken subvector space with subgroup first. Thanks for your help! I would appreciate if you could check if my third bullet indeed show that f has an inverse element!

Comment: I think it works, but it's a bit messy: you should prove $f=(f^{-1})^{ad}$ if $f^{-1}=f^{ad}$.